# System.data.sqltypes.sqltypeexception: 'sqldatetime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.'

Tags: c#, asp.net

This a bus booking project i've been working on and I'm getting an error that this date is overflowing it must be between the date specified in the question please help me. I can' t understand how to solve this error.

```
private void bindSearchDetails()
    {
        DataSet dsGetData = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();                                     
        if (connString.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connString.Open();
        }
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Origin",Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Origin"]));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Destination"]));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TravelDate", Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["TravelDate"]));
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "ispGetAvailableBusDetails";
        sqlCmd.Connection = connString;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        sda.Fill(dsGetData);
        if (dsGetData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            hlinkSearch.Visible = false;
            gvBusDetails.DataSource = dsGetData.Tables[0];
            gvBusDetails.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Trip not available, Please search again with different date')", true);
            hlinkSearch.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the query string parameters you tested?

Comment: what is the value of `Request.QueryString["TravelDate"]` ?

Comment: @KlausGütter I placed the from origin which is Crossroads and the to destination which was portmore and the travel date '03/02/2022'.  It's not accepting it to the database

Comment: Do you have anywhere an un-initialized datetime? The default value for a C# datetime cannot be represented in SQL's DATETIME

Comment: Being that you are getting your data from web request, I would pre-pull those into local variables and validate their content FIRST before even applying or attempting to apply to a query.  Yes, you are still parameterizing them, but obviously someone puts in crap values, you get crap output.

Answer (score 0):

*([Cross-posted from CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5323542/System-data-sqltypes-sqltypeexception-sqldatetime))*

Parse the date and check whether it is within the acceptable range:

```c#
DateTime travelDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(Request.QueryString["TravelDate"], out travelDate))
{
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TravelDate", travelDate);
}
else
{
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TravelDate", DBNull.Value);
}
```

Also, the `QueryString` indexer already returns a `string`; there's no need to call `Convert.ToString` on those values:

```c#
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Origin", Request.QueryString["Origin"]);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", Request.QueryString["Destination"]);
```

**NB:** If you want to allow dates outside of that range, change your SQL datatype from `datetime` to either `datetime2` or `date`, both of which allow the same range of values as the .NET `DateTime` type:
[Date and Time Data Types and Functions - SQL Server (Transact-SQL) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql)